# Navigation bar visibility on Samsung S8

Tags: android, navigationbar, samsung-mobile

As many of you already know, Samsung has introduced option to hide navigation bar by double-clicking on small dot in bottom-left corner.

I need to figure out if it is hidden or not, so I tried to do that by getting its height.
It looks like it always 144, no matter if it's visible or not.
Samsung does in its way, so probably this is not a good way to go.

Is there a way to figure out if navigation bar is hidden or not on Android devices?

Comment: Find a solution?

Comment: No, I did not.. I switched to a different approach. Sadly

Comment: check the question for the solution _[a helper method that does a pretty good job of letting me know that a device has a navigation bar toggled on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51317263/how-to-know-when-samsung-s8-s8-s9-ect-bottom-navigation-bar-is-visible)_